# cannot read properties of null (reading 'usecontext') when linking my own library to react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, package.json

I am developing my own react library called **@efishery/onefish-antd**, and I want to test it before I publish it. I am using `npm link` to import my library to my other react app, so the library seems installed in the react app **node_modules**

[image]

But, when I import one of my component like so

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from '@efishery/onefish-antd'

function App() {

  const onClick = () => {

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
          
        </a>
        <Button onClick={onClick}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This error appears

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

I have tried to publish it, and it seems like it is working just fine. I only got this issue when I use **npm link** or **npm install** to my own local library.

I have tried to re-install the node_modules, deleting the **package-lock.json** , but nothing works.

I can't publish the library every time I want to test it, it does not effective at all

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Does your library use react context? Maybe the `Button` is using `useContext` under the hood, so that the `useContext` will throw that error if you use it outside of context provider scope.

Comment: Seems like react is not installed or there is a version mismatch

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same issues it doesn't work locally but works well on publish.

Comment: @RajatVerma Unfortunately No, but luckily one of my co-workers give me a solution by bundling the library into a tarball file with `npm pack`, and then I install that tarbal file into my project

Comment: interesting, that works for me as well. I wonder what's the underlying issue in case of `npm link`. But thanks man, this will definitely help!

Comment: Any proper solution on this? Packing in tar is not a solution. I have my package and whenever I change something it rebuilds so the main app it also hot reloads. Having to pack manually install is no-go for developing with hot reloading

Answer (score 1):

I read the comments but here is a simple solution which I came to know:

`cd` into the react app (not the library) then: `cd node_modules/react && npm link`. Then go into your library and `npm link react`.

As a short explanation it syncs the react, both in the root project and in the library, so you will not get errors anymore.